# Pushing number to the end of a sentence - ieee refencing with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I have a question about improving the flow of textual citations.

When using `\textcite{Hunt}` as part of a sentence it will be typeset as

> Hunt [4] showed that this works.

I was wondering if there is any way to have the reference display as:

> Hunt showed that this works [4].

I know this can be achieved manually using

```
\citeauthor{Hunt} showed that this works \cite{Hunt}
```

but I was hoping a 'smart' method existed to some degree.  I have no idea if this is something that is possible, but thanks in advance none the less.

This should work as a MWE for this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{myreferences.bib}
@misc{Hunt,year = {2012},author= {Hunt}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}
\begin{document}

\textcite{Hunt} showed that this works. 

\citeauthor{Hunt} showed that this works \cite{Hunt}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you provide a small fully working example of how to do it manually, someone is more likely to devise a way to automate the process.

Comment: The tricky thing is making LaTeX detect the end of the sentence and only issue the 'buffered' citation there. Without additional markup that appears extremely tricky. The only way to do this that I can think of would require to make the `.` an active character, which I imagine would be risky since that definition could break uses of `.` in other contexts (file names, e.g. when you include images).

Comment: Maybe you could do this with LuaLaTeX in a callback to avoid making `.` active.

Comment: Or make a new command that has the whole sentence as a second argument - not very clean but it saves you one `\cite`. Something like `\newcommand{\citepush}[2]{\citeauthor{#1}#2\cite{#1}}` and then `\citepush{Hunt}{showed that this works}.`. Or is that too simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky thing here is that with `\textcite` LaTeX knows exactly where to put the output, but in something like

```
\Pushcite{sigfridsson} showed some very interesting things.
```

you have to rely on `biblatex` finding out where the sentence ends and where to place the citation.

If you are happy with additional markup to help `biblatex` along you can use the following

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newtoggle{cbx@pushcite}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\pushcite}
  {\ifundef\cbx@puhscite@savedcites
     {\gdef\cbx@puhscite@savedcites{\autocites}}
     {}%
   \gdef\cbx@pushcite@savedkeys{}%
   \boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@puhscite@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@pushcite@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@puhscite@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@pushcite@savedkeys}}%
   \global\toggletrue{cbx@pushcite}}

\newrobustcmd*{\Pushcite}{\bibsentence\pushcite}

\newcommand*{\releasecite}{%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@pushcite}%
  \ifundef\cbx@puhscite@savedcites
    {}
    {\cbx@puhscite@savedcites}%
  \gundef\cbx@puhscite@savedcites}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\Pushcite{sigfridsson} showed that many things happen in chemistry \releasecite.

\Pushcite{worman} showed E.~coli likes sun \releasecite.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

but that is only slightly less handy than the obvious

```
\Citeauthor{sigfridsson} showed many things \cite{sigfridsson}.
```

If you don't want additional markup, the only thing  we have to guide us where to discharge the citation is the full stop at the end of the sentence. It is possible to make it an active character, which means that it can behave like a macro. This can help us automatically issue `\releasecite` at the end of each sentence.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newtoggle{cbx@pushcite}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\pushcite}
  {\ifundef\cbx@puhscite@savedcites
     {\gdef\cbx@puhscite@savedcites{\autocites}}
     {}%
   \gdef\cbx@pushcite@savedkeys{}%
   \boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@puhscite@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@pushcite@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@puhscite@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@pushcite@savedkeys}}%
   \global\toggletrue{cbx@pushcite}}

\newrobustcmd*{\Pushcite}{\bibsentence\pushcite}

\newcommand*{\releasecite}{%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@pushcite}%
  \ifundef\cbx@puhscite@savedcites
    {}
    {\cbx@puhscite@savedcites}%
  \gundef\cbx@puhscite@savedcites}

\begingroup
\catcode`\.=\active
\gdef\mkperiodreleasecite{%
  \catcode`\.=\active
  \def.{%
    \ifnum\spacefactor=1000
      \space\releasecite
    \fi
    \origdot}%
}
\endgroup

\AfterEndPreamble{%
  \let\origdot=.
  \mkperiodreleasecite}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\Pushcite{sigfridsson} showed that many things happen in chemistry.

\Pushcite{worman} showed E.~coli likes sun.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

While this works in this example that approach has several drawbacks.

- Making characters active can mean that those characters fail to work correctly in different contexts. (Things seem to work OK in the example, but in a more general document I would expect errors or weird side effects.)
- We may fail to correctly identify what constitutes the end of a sentence. Here we used space factors to avoid classifying abbreviation dots as full stops, but that only works to some extent. For example the code will fail to correctly work for `Dr.~Smith`.

---

Given all that I'd probably stick to either citing with

```
\Textcite{sigfridsson} showed that there is a lot to this.

\Citeauthor{sigfridsson} could prove the converse \cite{sigfridsson}
```

Or, if you want to avoid duplication and can live with slightly awkward markup

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\defertextcite}{}
\newcommand*{\defertextcite@i}{}
\def\defertextcite#1#{\defertextcite@i{#1}}
\def\defertextcite@i#1#2#3{\citeauthor{#2} #3 \autocite#1{#2}}

\newcommand*{\Defertextcite}{\defertextcite}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\Defertextcite[380]{sigfridsson}{showed several great results}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```